# Creating one binary for multiple unit tests in Google's C++ Testing Framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

Currently I have a `test` folder with multiple source files for each test. On CMake, I previously defined a binary for each source file but decided that I should now combine all of them into a single binary and make use of the filters in GTest to select which tests I want to run. None of these source files has a `main()` function but I guess the GTest framework just implicitly calls it during runtime.

So now I created a test manager source file which has nothing except a  `main()` which calls `InitGoogleTests`  and `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` and includes all the test source files. According to Google, that's a 'hack to be used at last resort'.

How should I then properly do this? Should I really go and create header files for each of my test sources and write the declarations there and then include all these headers in my test manager source? Is there any other...easier... way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special with these files...

All of your `TEST_F` and similar macros will be linked together and run. This is googletest magic...

Actually you do not need this "test manager source" with `main()` - just use file from your googletest/googlemock distrubution:

> gmockxxx/src/gmock_main.cc

or

> gtestxxx/src/gtest_main.cc

Answer (score 0):

Include all source and header files you need for your tests into one project. You don't need to include a "main" source file, unless some special setup is needed before gtest initialization. Just link your test project with two GTest libraries:

```
-lgtest -lgtest_main
```

The latter `gtest_main` library contains the basic `main()` function.

It is described in [GTest Primer: Writing the main() function](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Writing_the_main()_Function)

---

You might have a case, where each of your tested classes depends on several source files (other helper classes). You would like to keep these tested classes in separate executables for testing cleanness, to ensure each of them use only needed files and doesn't depend on files used by other tested classes. This solution may also reduce compilation time.

In this case, you have to make your own test runner to execute all test executables, and possibly print which of them had errors. This is easy to do with Bash or Python.